# Rails 5: devise invitable add custom fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I'm trying to add devise invitable to my new application. I found a lot of information on the internet but there doesn't seem to be a go to solution.

So the problems I'm facing are the following:

1. When a user invites someone the account gets created, while the standard email template generated by devise says 'Your account won't be created...'
2. When a user clicks the activation link he gets redirect to the edit page, but when they submit their information my columns :fullname, :terms_of_service are not saved.

Probably I'm missing something.

This is my invitations_controller

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    User.invite!(invite_params, current_user)
      redirect_to dashboard_path
  end

  def update
    user = User.accept_invitation!(accept_invitation_params)
  end

  def edit
  end

  private

  def invite_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :ivitation_token, :provider, :skip_invitation)
  end

  def accept_invitation_params
    params.permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token, :fullname, :terms_of_service)
  end
end
```

My console output:

```
Processing by InvitationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/PoYvD7be0xpE1yBGI2EsojBU62o8d+Kcx0B8LgZ7DJkrqz2lCGs1YrA8d5ziwOAVH68u+1ij7ZacecVmNfaUQ==", "user"=>{"invitation_token"=>"4a24a37282a3881a4d595f251ea4deca4d0c25cbb966d50d8d622941a55c1a4c", "fullname"=>"Arnas Klasauskas", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "terms_of_service"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Einladen"}
Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :_method, :authenticity_token, :user, :commit
No template found for InvitationsController#update, rendering head :no_content
```

My application_controller

```
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation, keys: [:email, :fullname, :terms_of_service])
    end
```

Comment: Post your view file

Comment: Everything is working now, thank you.

Comment: Ok what's wrong  share to all

Comment: there is a little mispell, fix :ivitation_token with :invitation_token. Not related to your problem however

Answer (score 2):

So if you want to add custom parameters, you can simply add this line to your update method

```
User.accept_invitation!(update_resource_params)
```

Now you'll need to add the update_resource_params method to your invitations_controller with your custom fields:

```
def update_resource_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token, :fullname, :terms_of_service)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called when creating invitation.

```
  def invite_resource
    User.invite!(invite_params)
  end
```

This is called when accepting invitation.

```
 def accept_resource
    resource = resource_class.accept_invitation!(update_resource_params)
    resource
  end
```

This is where you customize your fields

```
def invite_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :invitation_token,...)
  end
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation, keys: [:name, :time_zone, :terms_of_service,...])
  end
```

Comment: does this answer the question ?